# How to access Namespaced JWT Claims in AWS HTTP API Gateway Request Mapping

Tags: jwt, terraform, aws-api-gateway, auth0

I'm trying to set up HTTP integration in AWS API Gateway v2 (aka HTTP API). In my config, I have a native JWT authorizer and want to **append one namespaced JWT access_token claims to HTTP request headers**.

As long as claims as simple name such as `sub` or `iss` this is working fine with the following mapping syntax:

```
append:header.simple = append:$context.authorizer.claims.simple
```

However, some of my claims are namespace with an `https://namespace/` prefix (is a requirement from Auth0 and cannot be changed). This is where mapper syntax is falling short for me.

Say my input JWT is like this:

```json
{
        "aud": "my.dev.api",
        "azp": "CCCC",
        "exp": "1610606942",
        "https://my.ns/account_no": "100368421",
        "iat": "1610598342",
        "iss": "https://mytenant.auth0.com/",
        "scope": "openid profile email account:admin",
        "sub": "auth0|user-id"
}
```

How can I map namespaced claim `https://my.ns/account_no`?

I tried `$context.authorizer.claims['https://my.ns/account_no']` with no luck. Here is the terraform setup I use:

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_integration" "root" {
  api_id           = aws_apigatewayv2_api.api.id
  integration_type = "HTTP_PROXY"

  connection_type      = "INTERNET"
  description          = "This is our GET / integration"
  integration_method   = "GET"
  integration_uri      = "http://${aws_lb.ecs_lb.dns_name}"
  passthrough_behavior = "WHEN_NO_MATCH"

  request_parameters = {
    "append:header.account_no" = "$context.authorizer.claims['https://my.ns/account_no']" <-- FAILING HERE
  }
}
```

Error I'm getting in terraform and dashboard is the same:

> Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression specified: $context.authorizer.claims["https://my.ns/account_no"]]

Thanks for your assistance.

[image: AWS error mapping namespaced claim]

Comment: For now, I'm using Lambda authorizer and inject header from `$context.authorizer.account_no`, however, I'd like to get the JWT authorizer working. It's faster and cheaper.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for that issue?